# convert blob file to text file as I am getting file in '"xXÛrÛ6}×LÿAõ;Ã8íC&¡Ò€liªEÉN&£Èµ"TŽ­¿ïx!'¶°ç," this format with cast_to_raw

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, data-conversion, file-conversion

How to get the text file from blob, I tried using :

```
SELECT UTL_I18N.RAW_TO_CHAR(dbms_lob.substr(BLOB_FILE),'AL32UTF8') 
FROM TABLE;
```

Also I tried :

```
SELECT utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2(dbms_lob.substr(BLOB_FILE)) 
FROM TABLE
```

But getting values like this :

```
xœXÛrÛ6}×LÿAõ;Ã8íC&¡Ò€liª›EÉžN&£Èµ„š"TŽ­¿ï„x!'¶°ç,€åb±`yN¶àŒÂ/}Ï¹üôÇ‡Æß_{Ý‡þuoB÷à<
```

How can we convert blob file to text?

Comment: Have you looked at [CONVERTTOCLOB](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/23/arpls/DBMS_LOB.html#GUID-6CCF8174-8A2D-4F3C-A179-A99790BD471D)?